# Reactive Cocoa - listening for notifications & memory management

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I would like to know if someone else had some issue with Reactive Cocoa listenForNotification method. 
I'm experiencing a retain cycle using the following code and my viewController dealloc method is never called.
If I don't listen for that notification my viewController is properly dealloc'ed

HERE IS THE UPDATE FULL BLOCK OF CODE, in which I call the method to listen for notifications:

```
RACSignal *postSignal = [RACSignal empty];        
postSignal = [[[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] rac_addObserverForName:kNotification object:self.conversation] takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal]] bind:^RACStreamBindBlock{
        return ^RACSignal *(NSNotification *note, BOOL *stop) {
            XXStatus status = [note.userInfo[@"status"] longValue];
            if (status == XXStatusPosted) {
                *stop = YES;
                return [RACSignal empty];
            } else {
                return [RACSignal error:note.userInfo[@"error"]];
            }
        };

[[[[RACSignal merge:@[uploadSignal, postSignal]] deliverOnMain] subscribeCompleted:^{
    [self doSomethingX];
} error:^(NSError *error) {
    [self doSomethingOnFail:error];
}] autoDispose:self];
```

Do you know how RAC memory management works for listening notifications? Where notification center is the default notification center in the app. And the method is included in a category extension of NSObject class.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: There's no code from the ReactiveCocoa library in that code listing.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the method is in a category of NSObject class that perform the following : [[notificationCenter rac_addObserverForName:name object:object]
            takeUntil:self.rac_willDeallocSignal] ... will edit my question thanks

Comment: Still not really enough code to help you. Presumably you are subscribing to the signal returned by the line of code you posted; if so, then it would be helpful for you to show us the body of the subscription block.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I've updated my  post in order to include more information. That's the basic structure I'm using to listen for a notification. I also posted what we did later , merging the signal with other signal. Hope this helps, I'm still experiencing the retain cycle.

Comment: Just a side note. There is no need to assign [RACSignal empty] to a variable and then immediately replace it with another value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't really a complete code snippet (it has unbalanced delimiters), so it's possible you've accidentally left something out that might have made it more clear. But it *looks* like the reason you have a retain cycle is in the very last line:

```
}] autoDispose:self];
```

That reference to `self` doesn't appear to be a **weak reference**, which means the bind block has an **strong** ("ownership") reference to `self`. If so, `self` will never be released, so the `self.rac_willDeallocSignal` never sends a value. And *that* means that the observer is never removed from the `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Erik, don't worry about the unbalanced delimiters, it's not a complete code, since I needed to change it a bit to hide real code due to licenses. But the good thing is that you're right about the strong reference ! Thanks for your help on this!